# Substrate Build a dApp Tutorial - TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: substrate

I was able to to run a local substrate node on my machine, finishing the first few tutorials - but am running into a problem with the "build-a-dapp" tutorial (https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/build-a-dapp/).

Its possible to successfully run the adjusted node. Building the custom front end is something of a two step process in the tutorial.
First running the "old" front end used in the very first build-your-own-node tutorial. Which is then started with yarn start - works fine. Afterwards the App.js file is adjusted, after saving it should switch to the new setup with the PoE UI elements. However, it drops the following error message for me:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

```
  142 | export default function TemplateModule (props) {
  143 |   const { api } = useSubstrate();
> 144 |   return (api.query.templateModule && api.query.templateModule.proofs
  145 |     ? <Main {...props} /> : null);
  146 | }
```

Compiled version:

```
212 | const {
  213 |   api
  214 | } = Object(_substrate_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["useSubstrate"])();
> 215 | return api.query.templateModule && api.query.templateModule.proofs ? /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["jsxDEV"])(Main, { ...props
      |            ^  216 | }, void 0, false, {
  217 |   fileName: _jsxFileName,
  218 |   lineNumber: 145,
```

I run it on iOS, all the other tutorials worked just fine, I already deleted everything and worked myself again through the tutorial to make sure I did not miss anything - is there any issue with the call of templateModule? Would appreciate any kind of help in this issue.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: Martin, This just got a face lift - https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-developer-hub.github.io/pull/954

Mind trying this one more time with the new docs and using substrate 3.0?

Comment: Hi NukeManDan, many thanks for the quick reply. Works smoothly now :) Highly appreciated.
For my understanding, was the issue in the original lib.rs code which only appeared after loading its TemplateModul function in the new App.js file of the front end? Any reason why the front end was now adjusted to keep the original code in App.js and to move the PoE dApp into TemplateModule.js? Trying to learn - btw, great tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the compliments :) - Template Module is a better place for this, as the example is a custom pallet then interfacing with a custom react component. I think this is a cleaner abstraction and also more extensible in a "copy paste" style of writing more functionality over time. Would you agree?

Comment: Yep, agree. Makes it easier to add more functionality when going through more of the tutorials